# Reactive Kafka consumer is rebalancing continuosly

Tags: java, apache-kafka, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

We are using 60 Partitions and have 70 consumers(10 more than partitions),There is no consumer Lag in any of the partitions, but rebalancing is happening in loop continuosly.
Processing time of Each kafkaEvent is 10ms

The following is the CommitFailed Exception which i get

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RebalanceInProgressException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is undergoing a rebalance for auto partition assignment. You can try completing the rebalance by calling poll() and then retry the operation.
```

I am using reactor-kafka:1.3.12 , reactor-core:3.4.18 , kafka-clients:3.0.1 , Java 17 version and Tomcat Webserver

```
Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"CommentedbootStrapServersUrl");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"user-groupid-1");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,"client-1");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,true);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,360000);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,300500);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,30500);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,300000);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,5);
      props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor");

ReceiverOptions<String,String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String,String>create(props)
              .addAssignListener(partitions ->LOGGER.info("onPartitionAssigned {}",partitions))
              .addRevokeListener(partitions -> LOGGER.info("onPartitionRevoked {}",partitions))
              .commitRetryInterval(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
              .commitBatchSize(3)
              .commitInterval(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
              .maxDelayRebalance(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
              .subscription(Collections.singleton("commentedTopicName"));

      Flux<ReceiverRecord<String,String>> inboundFlux = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
              .receive()
              .onErrorContinue((throwable,o) -> {
                  LOGGER.error("Error while consuming in this pod");
              })
              .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3)).transientErrors(true))
              .repeat();

              try {
                   Scheduler schedulers = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(2,2,"UThread");
                   inboundFlux
                           .publishOn(schedulers)
                           .doOnNext(kafkaEvent -> {
                                callBusinessLogic(kafkaEvent);
                                kafkaEvent.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                           })
                           .doOnError(e->e.printStackTrace())
                           .subscribe();
               } catch (Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

Needed help with fixing rebalancing issue, consumers are stable at times , but if a rebalance starts , then it never stops.

Comment: Hey mate! you may have to check the replication setting for your partitions. Kafka works on CAP theorem, if you have high number assigned to partitions and replica. Kafka will spent time in rebalancing to make it consistent (C), and the Availability (A) will suffer.

It looks like you choose Consistency + Partitioning scarifying Availability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming when you say 70 consumers you mean consumer instances within a group, not 70 different consumer groups. I think the cause of your continuous rebalancing is that you have more consumers than partitions. That means some consumers will never get a partition. I think that's a bad state for the rebalance. Even if that isn't the cause of the problem, there is no benefit in having more consumers than partitions. The number of partitions is the maximum amount or parallelization you can have. Try decreasing the number of consumers to 60, or increasing the number of partitions to 70.
Another common cause of constant rebalancing is that one or more consumers is taking longer than the timeout period to send a heartbeat. This can happen when it takes a long time to process one batch of data. Make the timeout period longer or request smaller batches.